# convert a csv to excel without using xlsx package

Tags: r

I want to convert a csv file to excel.

I found from the search in Internet that the best proposal it to use the library(xlsx) and use the write.xlsx(..) to write my dataframe to excel file.

However when I try to load and use the xlsx library and use it I receive the following:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Ban/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Could not find the specified mode. unit.
```

Is there any other way to convert the csv to excel or is there anyone faced the previous problem?

Comment: This  might be due to rJava looking for  x32 Java, where as your system is 64-bit. Go to [Java website](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) and download a 64 bit version then try reinstalling xlsx library. [see here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/)

Comment: If you have excel on your system it can be done with a VBS script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimum of research on CRAN reveals a number of packages:

- [XLconnect](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=XLconnect) needs Java
- [xlsx](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=xlsx) needs Java
- [openxlsx](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=openxlsx) does NOT need Java but is younger and not as widely used
- [writexls](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=writexls) uses Perl under the hood which most system have.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in [**rio**](https://github.com/leeper/rio) without needing a java dependency. It calls the **openxlsx** package.

```
install_github("leeper/rio")
library("rio")

# create an example CSV
export(mtcars, "mtcars.csv")

# convert the CSV to Excel (.xlsx)
convert("mtcars.csv", "mtcars.xlsx")
```

If you wanted to do this directly with openxlsx, you can run something like:

```
library("openxlsx")
write.xlsx(read.csv("mtcars.csv"), "mtcars.xlsx")
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of rio.

Comment: And by carrying the argument further you could use `openxlsx` directly as well?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Nothing against rio here but shouldn't you edit the answer towards the simplest and most direct solution?  Ie just openxlsx (or writexlsx or ...)?

Comment: If you just wanted to write a dataframe to Excel, yes, but OP wants to convert between files, and this way requires one function instead of two.