# Rjava 64-bit error

Tags: java, r, 64-bit, xlconnect

I am receiving this error when I use packages `XLConnect` and `rJava`.

```
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have not seen this specific error in any threads here on in this community. Though I do believe the issue to be related to some other threads.

I have downloaded 64-bit java, and have tried to fix the path to java with:
`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_65\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186040/convert-a-csv-to-excel-without-using-xlsx-package might help