# Why R is unable to load a shared object?

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am trying to use `XLConnect` library in R. If I execute

```
library(XLConnect)
```

I get the following error message:

```
JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

To resolve this problem I set first the `JAVA_HOME` variable:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_65')
library(XLConnect)
```

It looks like it helps me to come further but then I get another problem:

```
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll'
```

It wonder why R cannot load `rJava.dll`. At least this file is located in the folder where R searches for it:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\library\rJava\libs\x64
```

**ADDED**

Please note that the `rJava.dll` file exists and it is located there, where R is searching for it. I guess that the problem is in incompatibility between 32bit and 64bit versions. I assume that because R complains:

```
% 1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Well, why do R expect it to be a `` Win32 application`? First, my OS is 64bit, second my Java is also for the 64bit and finally, the `rJava.dll` object is located in the folder with ``x64` in the name (so, I assume it is also a 64bit version).

Comment: Create and place it the folder where it is looking for it?

Comment: Am i missing something? Those paths look the same to me.

Comment: Are you sure the java is the right one for your OS/r version ie 32 vs 64bit?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r and some other links in comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186040/convert-a-csv-to-excel-without-using-xlsx-package#comment46587465_29186040

Comment: @user20650, I have 64bit OS and my Java is for 64bit. So, it is consistent. However, in R error message I see: `% 1 is not a valid Win32 application`. Of course it is not, because it is a Win64 application. So, the question is why R expects a Win32 application and how to change it?

Comment: I'd recommend using `readxl` instead. The package includes C and C++ libraries, and it is simpler and probably faster to use. Get the excel data out of there as quickly as possible, then do post-processing in R: this is what `readxl` does well.

Comment: @Roman: you said you had 64bits OS and Java 64bits but what about R ? Are you using a 32bits or 64 bits version ?

Comment: ...and you've updated all of your packages and checked that the path is correct?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue . Please locate jvm.dll 
should be in (your JRE version could be different )

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\client
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin\server
```

add this path to your windows system path and you are good to go .but keep in mind the version of jre and R should be consistent,if your java is in `Program Files` its 64 bit so launch from `64 bit R`  if its in `Program Files (x86)`its 32 bit so use `32 bit R`

like in my case it showed error in 64 bit [image]

but worked perfectly in 32 bit 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You did use `/` instead of `\`.

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_65') 
library(XLConnect)
```

I am using UNIX. Therefore I cannot test it by myself but your path might be wrong as well.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120270/how-can-i-install-rjava-for-use-with-64bit-r-on-a-64-bit-windows-computer) you can search it by using this:

```
find.java <- function() {
    for (root in c("HLM", "HCU")) for (key in c("Software\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment", 
        "Software\\JavaSoft\\Java Development Kit")) {
        hive <- try(utils::readRegistry(key, root, 2), 
          silent = TRUE)
        if (!inherits(hive, "try-error")) 
          return(hive)
    }
    hive
}
```

credit goes to @nograpes for the function and this [article](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/) for helping me giving you the answer.