# rJava library not working. Unable to find jvm.dll

Tags: r, xlsx, rjava

I realize this question has been asked before but none of the solutions worked for me.

After a 'successful' install of rJava I try `library(rJava)` I receive an error that R cannot find `jvm.dll`. Here are the solutions I've tried:

- Setting my `PATH` to include a direct link to the `jvm.dll` directory. Also tried one level up
- Clearing the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable. Also setting `JAVA_HOME` to the directory of my `jvm.dll`
- Direct install from rforge.net using `install.packages('rJava', .libPaths()[1], 'http://www.rforge.net/')`. I receive this error:

  `Find Java...
  ERROR: cannot find Java Development Kit.
         Please set JAVA_HOME to specify its location manually`
- Attempted setting the path of `JAVA_HOME` using this command: `options(java.home="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_121\\bin\\client")`

Other potentially useful information:

- Going into cmd and running `echo %JAVA_HOME%` shows the correct directory
- I restarted RStudio after every attempt
- Running on Windows 7 64 bit.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Getting really frustrated trying to get this library working as it's needed for the xlsx library.

**SOLUTION:**

Egg on my face, the issue was that I accidentally pointed to environmental variable to an old 32 bit install of Java that I must have accidentally installed at some point in the last few years (thank you @user20650). Pointing everything back at the 64 bit version fixed things. For the record I *did* have to set JAVA_HOME to point to the correct directory. Also, make sure you have both the java JRE and JDK.

Comment: If you are usnig x64 R, then try installing x64 bit java https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp, as you seem to be setting path for x32

Comment: ps some non jave alts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186040/convert-a-csv-to-excel-without-using-xlsx-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Egg on my face, the issue was that I accidentally pointed to environmental variable to an old 32 bit install of Java that I must have accidentally installed at some point in the last few years (thank you @user20650). Pointing everything back at the 64 bit version (ie `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`) fixed things after running `install.packages('rJava', .libPaths()[1], 'http://www.rforge.net/')`.

For the record I did have to set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the correct directory. Also, make sure you have both the java JRE and JDK. Also, for some reason my anti-virus did not like letting that rforge install go through (didnt like the findjava.exe), so I had to pause it for a moment.